# Custom error message for response status 404

Tags: javascript, axios, http-status-code-404

Why can't I catch a custom error message after receiving an error with status **404**? I expected that in both approaches, the error message would be throwed to the nearest catch block.

**version 1:**

```
export const checkMovieExists = async (movieId) => {
  const url = `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}`;

  const movieExists = await axios
    .get(url)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        return true;
      }
      throw new Error(`Movie with ID ${movieId} not found.`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
      return false;
    });

  return movieExists;
};
```

console output: `"Request failed with status code 404"`

---

**version 2:**

```
export const checkMovieExists = async (movieId) => {
  const url = `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}`;

  try {
    const movieExists = await axios.get(url).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        return true;
      }
      throw new Error(`Movie with ID ${movieId} not found.`);
    });
    return movieExists;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return false;
  }
};
```

console output: `"Request failed with status code 404"`